# Get instagram user fans amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, instagram-api

I would like to know that is it possible to grab user's ig fans amount via url? I tried to get page content with curl but I was redirected to login page.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.instagram.com/user_name/'))
puts doc.to_html
```